# converting Correlated query to DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, correlated-subquery

I have a table Emails as below
Id,
Project,
Subject,
ReceivedDate

This table will hold emails . I am trying to add a calculate column Responded Status which should get populated on certain logic.
I have the SQL query which works well for me.

select E.Id,E.Project,E.Subject,E.ReceivedDate ,
case when (select count(E1.Id) from Emails E1
where E1.Project = E.Project and E1.ReceivedDate > E.ReceivedDate
and (E1.Subject like 'RE:%' or E1.Subject like 'FW:%') and E1.Subject like '%' + E.Subject + '%') ) > 0
then 'Yes'
else 'No' end as RespondedStatus
from Emails E

I need help in converting the SQL to DAX. I will use the DAX to populate the calculated col "RespondedStatus"

Appreciate suggestions/ ideas on this!!

Comment: what is between `select` and `, case`?

Answer (score 1):

```
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(
        Emails
        ,Id
        ,Project
        ,Subject
        ,ReceivedDate
    ) 
    ,"RespondedStatus", VAR currentProj = [Project]
                VAR currentReceivedDate = [ReceivedDate]
                VAR currentSubject = [Subject]
                VAR result =                    
                    COUNTROWS(
                        FILTER(
                            Emails
                            ,[Project]=currentProj
                            && [ReceivedDate]>currentReceivedDate 
                            && (
                                 (LEFT( [Subject], 3 ) = "RE:" 
                                  || LEFT( [Subject], 3 ) = "FW:"
                                 )
                                && CONTAINSSTRING(currentSubject, [Subject])    
                               )
                        )
                    )
                RETURN IF(result >0,"Yes","No")
)
```

Comment: Didn't test for sure ). Waiting for a feedback